# How to add Spring and Hibernate jars to OSGi project?

Tags: osgi

We have an OSGi project which needs spring and hibernate capability. I tried adding them separately as bundles, but they are not visible to the runtime environment. Below is a screenshot of our project (better picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6gV9.png). In the picture the plugins start with spring and hibernate contain the jars and I added them to the import packages in the needed bundles. I'm also attaching a sample manifest with this. Any help is appreciated. I always get classnotfoundexceptions for spring classes.

I created the jar bundles using eclipse's create plugin fro archives. In the wizard I selected them to be standard OSGi plugins (not sure if that is the right way). I'm building the project through IBM RAD (Aries).

[image]

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.xxx.scar.web1
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.xxx.scar.web1
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Web-ContextPath: /org.frb.scar.web1
Import-Package: javax.el;version="2.0";resolution:=optional,
 javax.faces,
 javax.faces.application,
 javax.faces.component,
 javax.faces.component.html,
 javax.faces.context,
 javax.faces.convert,
 javax.faces.el,
 javax.faces.event,
 javax.faces.lifecycle,
 javax.faces.model,
 javax.faces.render,
 javax.faces.validator,
 javax.faces.webapp,
 javax.servlet;version="2.5",
 javax.servlet.annotation;resolution:=optional,
 javax.servlet.http;version="2.5",
 javax.servlet.jsp;version="2.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.el;version="2.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext;version="2.0",
 org.frb.scar.entity,
 org.frb.scar.manager,
 org.frb.scar.services,
 org.frb.scar.utils,
 org.springframework.beans,
 org.springframework.beans.annotation,
 org.springframework.beans.factory,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.access,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.serviceloader,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml,
 org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors,
 org.springframework.beans.support
```

and more spring jars, until web.

**Error**

- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  and many....

Thanks,
Bab.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.

Package `org.springframework.web.context.request` is not listed in the imports of your bundle.

Comment: The imports is just a sample, as the list is too big I didn't put the whole thing. I have all the spring web packages in the import. When I add the web project in the dynamic web project section of the manifest, everything works fine. But when the web project is added as a web bundle then the problems start.As OSGi looks for the libraries during the run time, not sure how to make them visible.

Comment: "When I add the web project in the dynamic web project section of the manifest" << what does any of that mean?

Comment: I'm building this project in IBM RAD. That sentence is relevant to the OSGi application's manifest console. Pardon my way of explanation.

Comment: @Bab The problem with using RAD-specific jargon to explain your problem is that non-RAD users cannot help you. If you can explain in terms of the underlying OSGi concepts then a wider audience of experts on StackOverflow may be able to understand and help.

Comment: Have you tried checking the status of the spring bundles at runtime to see if they resolved properly?

Comment: @Robin Could you please detail little bit?

Comment: @Bab - Well, that is implementation specific, but from an OSGi console you can get a list of all the spring bundles.  Then make sure the one that actually contains the package in question is both installed and resolved.  For example, in equinox you would type "ss org.spring" and it would list all bundles with this substring as part of their name along with their status.